# Почему скрипты прописанные в html выполняются не по порядку?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
У меня есть такой html код
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/outside_script.js"></script>
    <p>HTML page</p>
    <script src="js/for_console.js"></script>   
    <script>
        alert("Hello, World!");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

В outside_script.js прописано

```
document.write("<h1>123456789</h1>");
```

В for_console.js прописан вывод сообщения в консоль через console.log.
Почему сначала появляется алерт, а только после этого прогружается страница и первый скрипт? По задумке сначала должен выполниться первый скрипт и написать "123456789", после этого должен прописаться тег "р" и только после этого появиться алерт. В чем ошибка? Что нужно сделать что бы скрипты выполнялись по порядку?

Comment: пропиши вместо document.write в внешних скриптах alert, тогда будет все по порядку. Просто прорисовка документа долго обрабатывается.

Answer (score 0):

Браузеры сканируют страницу на предмет скриптов и загружают их параллельно в целях увеличения производительности. Для соблюдения порядка загрузки внешних скриптов используйте аттрибут `defer`:

```
<script defer src="js/outside_script.js"></script> /* 2-ой  */
<p>HTML page</p>
<script defer src="js/for_console.js"></script>   /* 3-ий */
<script>
  alert("Hello, World!"); // --- выполнится первым, т.к. defer применяется только для внешних
</script>
```

Больше информации: https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer#defer